# how to have two images in one row in php from array

Tags: php

Please help me I have just pulled images from gallery using PHP. But now I just want to display two images in one row. Return it in `$content` that I have specified.

Please help me.

```
function CreateGalleryImages($types) {

    $galleryArray = array();
    $galleryModel = new GalleryModel();
    $galleryArray = ($galleryModel -> getGalleryByTypes($types));
    $result = "";

    foreach ($galleryArray as $gallery) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++){ 
            $result = "<td>"
                      ."<img runat = 'server' src = 'http://localhost/schoolwb/event/$gallery' height=500 width=500 />"
                      ."</td>";
        }
        $result = "<tr>.$result.</tr>";
    }
    return "<table class = 'GalleryTable'> . $result . </table>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `concatenate` the result and to store in `$result`.

Try This

```
<?php
function CreateGalleryImages($types){
  $galleryArray = array();
  $galleryModel = new GalleryModel();
  $galleryArray = ($galleryModel->getGalleryByTypes($types));
  $result = "";

  foreach ($galleryArray as $gallery){
    $cl = "";
    for ($i = 0;$i<2;$i++){ 
      $cl .= "<td>"
               ."<img runat = 'server' src = 'http://localhost/schoolwb/event/$gallery' height=500 width=500 />"
             ."</td>";
    }
    $result .= "<tr>.$cl.</tr>";
  }
  return "<table class = 'GalleryTable'>.$result.</table>";
}
?>
```